# Xcode PATH environment variable

Tags: xcode, macos, environment-variables

I am trying to compile an Xcode project that uses scripts to build some external (go) code. These scripts were build with the assumption that their external dependencies are on the $PATH. However, I am so far unable to get Xcode to use a PATH environment variable that includes the additions I need.

Is there a way to do this WITHOUT having to edit the Xcode project itself or the scripts? (I really don't want to edit these as these are shared with a larger team)

I have tried to use the LaunchAgents approach suggested in for example https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219042108-Setting-global-environment-variables-on-OS-X, but haven't had success with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever the script is called in xcode, that call would have to be amended to include the desired environment variable- but you don't want to modify the project. I would suggest putting symbolic links to the external dependencies somewhere in the default $PATH, where your scripts are expecting them to be.